# Ruby On Rails : local_time gem : I dont want it to wrap date with <time> tag

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sorting, view, datatables, localtime

I have been using [local_time](https://github.com/basecamp/local_time) to convert servertime to client local time. However now I am using [datatables](https://www.datatables.net/) and to sort `date/time` columns. I have to use `date-moment.js` plugin of `Datatables` which uses [moment.js](http://momentjs.com/docs/) to handle date conversions.

My problem is: the `local_time`'s view helper is wrapping the date with `< time >` tag like this

```
<time data-format="%B %e, %Y %l:%M%P"
      data-local="time"
      datetime="2013-11-27T23:43:22Z"
      title="November 27, 2013 6:43pm EDT"
      data-localized="true">November 27, 2013 6:43pm</time>
```

The wrapping thing is creating problem for `moment.js` to get the actual `date-time` as it expects. I need it to convert the date-time but not wrap with `<time>` tag. Is it possible. If yes How?

Comment: In which format you want date-time ?

Comment: @YogeshKhater I want datetime in any format like `%B %e, %Y`,`%m/%d/%Y`, `%b %d, %Y`

Comment: local_time also provides javascript API, so you can use it instaed of using local_time helper,

LocalTime.strftime(new Date, "%B %e, %Y")

Comment: hey, can you suggest me another similar gem

Comment: I don't find any similar gem, but `local_time` provides good support for converting time zones on both client and server side.
If you don't want to use JavaScript API, then you can also extract time from string returned by `local_time` helper.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

currently created a helper method to extract the core date from the string returned by the gem's `local_date` method
in `views/`

`<%= extract_date(local_date(workflow.created_at, CommonConstants::DATE_FORMAT_LONG)) %>`

```
  # Parse the string generated by local_time gem
  # Expectation :
  #   "<time data-format=\"%B %e, %Y\" data-local=\"time\" datetime=\"2015-10-28T11:19:54Z\">October 28, 2015</time>"
  def extract_date(date_string)
    date_string.split('>').pop.split('</')[0] rescue ''
  end
```